# What characterizes a Lisp dialect?

Tags: lisp

**What I am asking**

What characteristics define a Lisp dialect as a dialect (and not some other language entirely)?

**What I am *not* asking**

Which dialect is the best? --or-- which dialect should I learn? --or-- Lisp vs. another language.

Comment: Do you consider e.g. [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)) a *language* or a *dialect*? How about [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp)? What about Lisp-*like* "languages"? How about a language that uses all the properties of List except the parentheses? Is only the traditional Lisp from the late 1950's the one and only "true" Lisp?

Comment: A language is a dialect with a standards organisation.  In other words: as with natural languages the difference is social and political, not technical.

Comment: Note I have modified my answer (which you accepted): you might want to check you are still happy with it.

Comment: @tfb That is only a joke, though. Some programming languages which do not have ISO standards are nevertheless well-documented. It is easy to tell what is a dialect and what isn't. Some languages are not necessarily that well documented, yet are effectively specified by their (one and only) implementation. If a second implementation is made, we know which is the original language and which is the dialect.

Comment: "a (programming) language is a dialect with a standards organization" is an imitation of another quote, namely  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_language_is_a_dialect_with_an_army_and_navy     It isn't nearly as truthful as the original, I'm afraid.

Comment: Something can be both a language (in the sense of being a well-documented, well-specified and implemented thing full of conscious design decisions) yet also be a dialect (sharing syntax, semantics and concepts with some significant other language).   Ideally, every dialect would be a language.  Implementations of standardized languages are also dialects; e.g. GCC understands dialects of C, such as GNU C.

Comment: @Kaz Yes, I don't think the standards organisation has to be formally that: Python has such a thing in the sense I meant (even though it's almost a single-implementation language).  My point was that there is no useful technical distinction, as with natural languages. (Why is Scots a language, but the language spoken by people who live in Newcastle a dialect of English?  Politics.)

Comment: @tfb Looking at examples of Newcastle dialect, it doesn't seem like a dialect of English, but a Germanic language related to English. A dialect of English is something that should be highly intelligible to any speaker of any other English dialect around the world. E.g. we take a Canadian, Australian, South African or Brit (not from Newcastle), and they can all understand it.

Comment: @Kaz Yet Newcastle English, or the now mostly extinct Devon dialect is English but Scots is not (native UK English speakers, especially those from lowland Scotland, would say), which was my point: there simply is no useful unambiguous distinction between the two terms, and any attempt to draw such becomes rapidly unhelpful.  As this one is in danger of becoming.

Comment: @tft The distinction between "language" and "dialect" is crystal clear: a language is a syntax and semantics and all that, and "dialect" is a word that relates two or more languages; we need at least two languages to say that one is a dialect of another. That's where all the contention is: is the relationship close enough to use the word "dialect" for those two or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should resist adding an answer, but I can't.  As I said in a comment: a language is a dialect with a standards organisation -- there *is* no technical definition which is really useful.  That being said here are some attributes I think a Lisp should have to be a Lisp.  Note I am not saying 'a dialect of Lisp'.

### Strong requirements

- **It must be an expression language.**  This means that there is only one class of thing: expressions, which have values, rather than expressions, which have values, and statements, which don't.  The values of expressions can be undefined (and obviously in some Lisps they can have multiple values).  This rules out C, Python and so on.  Apart from being obviously a desirable characteristic, macro systems are a pain for non-expression languages.
- **It should have a seamless macro system in which the full language is available**.  By 'seamless' I mean that macros should be a natural thing to write, rather than some arcane add-on possibly involving a separate preprocessing step, and macros should have the same status as any other construct in the language.  By 'the full language' I mean that it should be possible to compute the expansions of macros using the whole language (including macros) and this should be the *same* language as the language for which the macros are being expanded.  There may be a more restrictive layer as well.
- **It should have a syntax of minimum commitment.**  What this means is that the syntax of the language, including the parse tree derived from the surface syntax on which macros act, should not be too specific about what things *mean*.  So, for instance, there should not be a big syntactic distinction between built-in constructs (the syntax around `if` & other conditionals for instance) and, say, function calls.  The reason for this is macros: in the presence of a macro system *what the syntax means is defined by the programmer*, and having special privileged things in the syntax of the language is the enemy of that.  This also means that the parse tree that macros work on should be rather general and without any semantics attached to it.
- **It should have unrestricted `lambda`.**  It does not have to be called `lambda` (it could be `fn` or anything else), but it should not be restricted in any way.  In particular it should be clear that function definitions could be done in terms of `lambda` & some macrology.
- **It should have conses and lists made of them.**  So `(a . b)` is a cons, and `(a b c)` is the same as `(a . (b . (c . ())))`.  Conses and lists don't have to be written like that, but the notation should be simple and it probably helps if they are.  In particular lists should be singly-linked, and not arrays dressed-up.
- **It should have symbols.**  Not strings which you can pretend are symbols, but symbols.

### Weaker requirements

These are things which I think are not strictly necessary, but it helps.

- **Parenthesized prefix notation for source.**  If this is the case then conses and lists should also be written in the same notation.
- **Type declarations should be optional.**  It should be possible to write code with no type declarations.
- **Dynamic, strong typing.**  This is not really a requirement: I can imagine a Lisp which did heroic type inference everywhere and actually was essentially statically-typed.  But, if you can leave out type declarations (previous point) then this is really indistinguishable from dynamic typing except for performance and heroism.

### Matters of good taste

These are not requirements at all but I would not use a Lisp seriously that did not have these features.

- **Conversational & incremental development style.**  This does *not* mean 'fancy IDE', it means that you hold a conversation with the language implementation in which you define and redefine things, ask it questions about things and to perform tasks for you and it talks back to you.  It also means that the implementation should be robust: talking to an implementation which dies every time you make an off-by-one error is like talking to someone whose hair catches on fire every time you say something contentious.
- **Careful arithmetic.**  This means that it should be possible to get answers which are numerically correct where that is reasonably easy (so there should be proper integers and rationals, but machine floats are OK when you need to resort to reals) as well as answers which are convenient.  If only one option is provided it should be the correct one.

---

### Notes

There have been some comments arguing that some of these requirements should be dropped.

#### Ancient Lisps

Before about 1963, Lisp didn't have macros: the [original paper on Lisp](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.html) makes no mention of them, for instance: the paper in which they were first discussed is [here](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6111), I think.  So before 1963 the language called LISP was not a Lisp by my definition.  The only way to allow this language to be a Lisp by the definition given here would be to say that to be a Lisp today you *don't need a macro system*, which I think would be clearly absurd.

So you either need to accept that the definition of what it means to be a Lisp has changed over time and the pre-1963 Lisp was perhaps 'old Lisp', or you could say that it was *part* of a Lisp.  Either is fine: dropping macros is not.

#### Lists should be made of conses

It's tempting to say -- especially if you want, say, Python to be a Lisp -- that the whole cons thing is a red-herring: a language with lists which are extensible arrays can be a Lisp.  This is also wrong, because the programs you write in a language with lists which are extensible arrays are *nothing like* the programs you write in a language where lists are chains of conses.

Consider this task: given a list (possibly a long list), pick n randomly-chosen elements from it.  Here is a simple CL function to do this:

```
(defun pick-n-random-elements (n l)
  (loop repeat n
        collect (nth (random (length l)) l)))
```

This function is *terrible* Lisp: it calls `length` and `nth` on every iteration.  It's the kind of function you give as an example to students to see if they have understood how lists work in Lisp.

But in a language where lists were extensible arrays this function would be *completely fine*: the equivalent Python function

```
from random import randint

def pick_n_random_elements(n, l):
    r = []
    for i in range(n):
        r.append(l[randint(0, len(l) - 1)])
    return r
```

while not being very idiomatic Python, it doesn't have the same performance horrors lurking in it.  (I think the idiomatic Python would probably be

```
from random import choice

def pick_n_random_elements(n, l):
    return [choice(l) for i in range(n)]
```

although I'm not quite sure.)

To do this in Lisp, something you might write something like this:

```
(defun pick-n-random-elements (n l)
  (labels ((pick (n tail elts accum)
             (cond ((null elts)
                    accum)
                   ((= (first elts) n)
                    (pick n tail (rest elts) (cons (first tail) accum)))
                   (t
                    (pick (1+ n) (rest tail) elts accum)))))
    (pick 0 l (sort (loop with len = (length l)
                          repeat n
                          collect (random len))
                    #'<)
          '())))
```

Note that this will return the reverse of the sequence that the previous function returned for a given random seed: assuming you actually want *random* elements this doesn't matter.  Note also it depends on tail-call elimination to be efficient which, while very natural Lisp style, you can't quite assume in CL -- here's a version which I think is both idiomatic Lisp and does not rely on that:

```
(defun pick-n-random-elements (n l)
  (let* ((len (length l))
         (indices (sort (collecting (repeat n (collect (random len))))
                        #'<))
         (tail l)
         (i 0))
    (collecting
      (while (not (null indices))
        (while (and (not (null indices))
                    (= (first indices) i))
          (collect (first tail))
          (setf indices (rest indices)))
        (setf tail (rest tail)
              i (1+ i))))))
```

And of course this uses three different non-standard macros: `repeat`, `while` and `collecting` / `collect` (the first two are trivial, the last is I suppose something everyone has written at some point), thus nicely showing that languages without macro systems are not Lisps as well.

These examples should convince you that, while a language which has lists which are extensible arrays might superficially look like a Lisp, the programs you write in it are enormously different than the programs you would write in a language with lists which are made of conses: if you tried to convert these programs to Lisp they would very often have catastrophic performance problems.  The reverse can also be true: it's easy to write programs in a Lisp which in an extensible-array language result in repeatedly copying a large array with terrible performance problems.

#### Concentrating on what matters

What I've tried to do here is to concentrate on what matters: it's easy to say that something which superficially 'looks like' a Lisp is a Lisp, or that a language which has some family resemblence to a Lisp is one: Norvig for instance has [famously said](http://norvig.com/python-lisp.html)

> Python can be seen as a dialect of Lisp with "traditional" syntax (what Lisp people call "infix" or "m-lisp" syntax).

I believe he's wrong: Python is not an expression language, doesn't have conses, has no macro system, has a crippled lambda, has no symbol type and doesn't really have a syntax of minimal commitment.  It's not a Lisp.

Instead I've tried to focus on what it's like to write programs in a Lisp (and what it's like to program in one today, not in 1960), because I think that's what matters.  And I think my strong requirements for being a Lisp are critical to what it's like to program in one: if any of them don't hold for a language then programming in it is a very different experience to programming in a Lisp.

---

This is, of course, just my opinion, albeit my opinion based on over 30 years of writing Lisp (I've just realised this: I'm not sure whether I should be depressed about it or not).

Comment: So Clojure is not a lisp dialect with its non pair list type? The first lisp is not a lisp with its lack of macros? Pre R5RS are not lisp dialects with it's lack of macros?

Comment: @Sylwester: if Clojure doesn't have conses then I'd argue it's not a Lisp, yes.  Obviously what makes a Lisp a Lisp has changed over time, the same way what makes English English has (is the language Chaucer wrote English?  it was once), and in particular before 1963 (or before macros first appeared which may have been slightly earlier than that) then 'having macros' would not have been a requirement.  Every Scheme implementation I've used, back to the 1980s, has had macros: they just weren't *standardised* because of the hygiene problems.  Finally did you read the 'just my opinion' bit?

Comment: I agree that it is your opinion. If you find Java 1.0 code it won't compile on a modern compiler but it is Java. It's just an older version of the language. Old English is an older version of English, but it is English. The code that run on the 1958 lisp is Lisp. The original interpreter has to be considered a lisp dialect since it is the ancestor of all modern lisps, including Clojure. It was how lisp was originally defined.

Comment: @Sylwester: basically very few functions from Lisp I are in Clojure, no Interpreter, no cons-bases lists, no dynamic binding, ...

Comment: @Sylwester: the relationship between Lisp and Clojure is more like the relationship between the first C implementation and Java: similar syntax principles and no shared programs due to basic incompatibility.

Comment: @Sylwester I've added some notes to my answer explaining some of my reasoning.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Common Lisp and Scheme programs are not compatible, but they are both considered Lisp dialects. Almost all modern programming languages today are C(B) dialects and it is of course an Algol dialect (best language designed by committee). It's possible to make small polygots that runs in the different dialects, probably harder to make polygots between languages that are not considered dialects. ONe could cosider French and Italian Latin dialects. Learning French for an italian would be easier than learning Korean because of that. Same holds for Lisp and C(Algol) dialects.

Comment: @Sylvester: Scheme and Common Lisp used to be more compatible and there are were even substantial programs which ran in both languages with the help of small compatibility layers (not interpreters or compilers). Over time these dialects diverged and are no longer compatible in an useful way. Clojure never had ANY compatibility with Scheme or Common Lisp, no programs ran in Clojure and Lisp/Scheme, and there is no compatibility layer for those, the user groups are different, the tools are different, the libraries are different, ...

Languages mostly are a social phenomenon.

Comment: @Sylvester. The most basic stuff, the core data structure, which is in every Lisp text book and zillion lines of code: `(a . b)` is a cons cell with car and cdr in Scheme and Lisp. In Clojure it is something like a sequence with three elements.

Comment: @RainerJoswig There are many lisp dialects that require proper lists and in those cases `.` can be used as an operand just like `+` and `/`.In CL the lambda list is always proper and most code is proper.The strength of using pairs is that you build lists by consing and not use more memory than the extra word for the new pair.This is also true for Clojure lists since it basically is a special vector where the last element is the cdr and the other elements are addressed words spaces for pointers that you can fill in.A 30 element list might use one cons of 256 bytes instead of almost the double.

Comment: @Sylwester: these sequences and lazy sequences are a completely different data structure with a completely different API, different time/space complexity and different capabilities/restrictions ('persistence', immutability, ...). This stuff is so different, that it shares ZERO code with Lisp dialects - it's a different language. If you don't share vocabularity, semantics, pragmatics - then it's not the same language.

Answer (score 1):

If your language has fully parenthesized polish prefix notation and thus can represent code as data, then it is a lisp dialect.

Of course some might want to require pairs as a built in type and lambda for them to be 100% sure, but remember that Clojure doesn't have pairs and the lack of lambda might be overcome by local define and passing that instead. Thus keeping it simple and just look at the notation and code as data might be the best approach.

For the languages that does not have S-expressions as its code it's more of an opinion. You can make a set of c macros such that an algol type notation like:

```
car(cons("a", "b")); // => "a"
```

What should `read` do in this laguage? Should it accept `'cons("a", "b")` or `'(cons "a" "b")`. It lacks just a syntax parser to become 100% a lisp dialect f `read` already reads s-expression and not the real synta of this language, but without it's not 100% lisp.

Answer (score 1):

#### My definition of lisps

A lisp family language is one that

1. has s-expression(-based) syntax.
2. has "prefix style" function application.
3. has so-called "lisp-style lists" constructed from cons cells.

#### Dialect? Language?

What makes a language a dialect of another language is really vague. C-style languages are obviously never refered to as C dialects, but for Lisp family languages, because they seem to have a common syntax (s-exp) and look the same to most people, they end up being called dialects.

I think the only "dialects" of a language are its own implementations. Scheme to Clojure to Common Lisp is like JavaScript to Perl to C, all very distinct from each other, and I think calling them Lisp dialects would only be confusing.

Even when I define it this way, it's still really opinionated. Chicken Scheme and Guile Scheme are both Scheme implementations, and they differ from each other enough to be Scheme dialects, but then I don't think Racket (#lang racket) should be called a Scheme dialect (or  even a Scheme implementation).

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. With only rare exceptions, a language is a Lisp if it has "Lisp" in its name somewhere. With pretty much no exceptions, it isn't Lisp if it doesn't have "Lisp" in its name.

Most people who are sufficiently serious and dedicated to pitch a significant new language to the world know better than to give it a name based on "Lisp" when they know that it isn't really. (One practical consequence of doing so is a good way to draw a lot of sharp criticism, which will relentlessly continue for the lifetime of that project, and they know it.)

And if someone makes something which is obviously a Lisp, it is a conscious effort to make a Lisp, rather than by accident, and so the name reflects that.

So, simply look at the name. If it doesn't have "Lisp" in it, then it isn't one, by the authors' explicit (or perhaps implicit) admission.

This guideline, taken too literally, is not totally reliable, but it is better than many.

For instance, James Gosling once made something which represented lists as character strings containing the textual representation with parentheses and all. It was called MockLisp, and existed in support of an Emacs-like editor. However, though it's a name with "Lisp" in it, the interpretation of the plain meaning of "mock" makes the truth clear. The name has since been rectified to Java, in any case, so it is no longer a factor.

There has been another case of someone making a non-Lisp and calling it Lisp. That person was a clever psychologist who specifically wanted to invite the aforementioned criticism as a form of trolling, to bring attention to his project while in the same master stroke create an opportunity to belittle the critics, painting them as unfriendly, petty and stuffy.